# Application is getting crashed while using Handle bars in Nodejs app

Tags: node.js, express-handlebars

I am using Handlebars Template engine in my node.js application but app is getting crashed. Public is the folder in which i have all the .hbs files. Inside Public i have one folder name 'layouts' in which i have layout.hbs file  Here's is what i have done:

I have tried writing handlebars instead of hbs...this could be stupid though but that also didn't work out.

app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const sessions = require('express-session');
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');


app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/public/layouts/'}));
app.set('public', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(morgan ('short'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'50mb'})); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true, limit:'50mb'}));
app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    console.log("Responding in Browser..");
    res.render('signIn');
});
```

signIn.hbs
It is having simple html code without html and body tags.

layout.hbs

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
   </head>
  <body>
     {{{body}}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Error which i am getting.
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
The server is up...
express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead app.js:238:13
_http_server.js:208
    throw new ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE(originalStatusCode);
    ^

RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: error
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:208:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (F:\Angular\GeneDetailsNode\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:44:26)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (F:\Angular\GeneDetailsNode\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:44:26)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:199:8)
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:585:9)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:709:5)
    at writeend (F:\Angular\GeneDetailsNode\node_modules\express-session\index.js:262:22)
    at Immediate.onsave (F:\Angular\GeneDetailsNode\node_modules\express-session\index.js:336:11)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Don't you need an app.listen somewhere for express to work?

Comment: Care to post information on what version of node.js you're using? I can't reproduce this with node 10.15.3 and freshly installed packages.